# Can't terminate / suspend a background job

Tags: kill, cat, background-process, job-control

I wanted to do a test for the Job Control Commands.

So, I ran a `cat` command and then made it a background job using the `bg`command after stopping it with `Ctrl +Z`.

Now I wanted to first terminate that background process, so I used the command `%kill-2%2` as the Process ID was [2] but it gave me an error saying "No such job". I tried it will `%kill-9%2` but same error.

I checked it with `fg` command and that job was still running and it came on foreground

Similarly, I wanted to suspend a background job, so I used the command `%kill-19%2` but it gave me an error that "No such Job"

I would like to know my fault or error.

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually typing which is why I hesitate in providing a direct answer.  Did you type `kill -2 %2` (with proper spacing and no beginning `%`)?

Comment: No @JuliePelletier I typed `%kill-2%2` without any space because if I give a space then it gives me an error "Too many arguments"

Comment: Then go ahead and try it as I said: `kill -2 %2`.  If that doesn't work, show us the exact command and error message.

Comment: Yeah, It is working. Thanks a lot. I have a question that why some websites say to use % sign before that "kill" word ?

Comment: Many shell command examples show the prompt before the command, but of course you're not supposed to type the prompt

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner you are right and I knew that we don't write the prompt. Actually, I forgot to consider that % sign as a prompt as I was used to with $ prompt and as a result, it wasted my time XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be `kill -2 %2` with proper spacing.

The `%` sign at the beginning of your line is probably just the prompt they are using (`PS1`).